# How I can show label in the center location of polygon in azure map?

Tags: javascript, angular, centering, geofencing, azure-maps

I need to show label in the centre location of the polygon in Microsoft azure map.
Please help me in this regards. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, can you show what is your actual code, and what have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of approaches. The easiest is to simply use a symbol layer and connect it to a data source that has a polygon in it. The symbol layer will automatically render labels for polygons, although the placement isn't the greatest for some polygons. Here is an example: https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/?search=polygon%20label&sample=Polygon%20labels%20-%20symbol%20layer

The second approach is to calculate the center of the polygon and create points for each label. Here is an example: https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/?search=polygon%20label&sample=Polygon%20labels%20-%20calculated